# g++ unrecognized option not part of the command

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to compile a project, I used `make` and got the following output

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I include/ -o build/example.o -c example/example.cpp
as: unrecognized option '--64'
```

The error states that the option `--64` is used and unrecognized while it is not in the command.
Other occurrences online of this error suggests changing `--64` to `--m64`. This problem is related to the gcc version used.

But the option is not present in my case, how can this error appear while the command does not contain the specified option ?

Edit: `make -m` results in the same output.
And the error occurs even when running the g++ command manually.

Edit: The error appears in the terminal after sourcing a file: `source setup.bash` (required by the project for some operation)

The script exports the following variable but they don't seem to be in relation with gcc.

- OPENOCD_SCRIPTS
- IDF_PATH
- IDF_TOOLS_EXPORT_CMD
- IDF_PYTHON_INSTALL_CMD
- IDF_PYTHON_ENv_PATH

It also adds some path to `PATH`

Even with this information, I still don't get why the error occurs.
Even if the gcc version was changed because of the paths added to `PATH`, the option is not part of the command.

Edit: After `source setup.bash`,

`gcc` is still the same

```
$ type gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
...
```

`as` changes

```
$ type as
as is /usr/bin/as
$ as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
...
```

```
$ type as
as is /path/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r3-8.4.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/as
$ as --version
GNU assembler (crosstool-NG esp-2020r3) 2.31.1
...
```

Comment: Maybe there is an incompatibility between gcc/g++ and as. Compare the output of `type gcc`, `gcc --version`, `type as` and `as --version` before and after sourcing `setup.bash`. Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: The option is probably coming from a built-in *spec string* for the assembler command. See for example [3.20 Specifying Subprocesses and the Switches to Pass to Them](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) - you may see errors like this for example when your gcc is part of a cross-compiler toolchain but it is mistakenly locating the system's native binutils (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gcc.gnu.org](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) states that

> gcc is a driver program. It performs its job by invoking a sequence of other programs to do the work of compiling, assembling and linking.

`as` is one of the programs invoked by gcc.

The `setup.bash` script did not change the path to `gcc` but it did for `as`.
The error is thus thrown by the replacing `as` program.